# Postgres Update Records in Loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, postgresql-9.1

I have an `Employee` table where `DEPTCODE` is null.

```
ID        NAME        AGE        DEPTID      DEPTCODE        
----      ----------  -----      ----------  -------      
1         Paul        32         2                 
2         Allen       25         1
```

And a `Department` table like this:

```
ID        DEPTNAME    DEPTCODE     
----      ----------  -----      
1         HR          DEP-01         
2         ADMIN       DEP-02
```

How to update `DEPTCODE` in the `Employee` table by querying `DEPTCODE` from the `Department` table?

I have tried this;

```
DO $$
BEGIN
FOR depart IN
        SELECT * FROM schema."Department"
    LOOP
        Update table schema."Employee" set "DEPTCODE"=depart."DEPTCODE"
          where "DEPTID"=depart."ID";
    END LOOP;
    END; $$
```

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? If yes you should plan your upgrade now. That version is no longer supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loop necessary. Postgres allows to join two tables in an UPDATE statement:

```
update "Employee" e
  set "DEPTCODE"=depart."DEPTCODE"
from "Department" depart
where e."DEPTID"=depart."ID";
```

---

But you shouldn't really do this. Storing copies of data in related tables it not a good database design. You can always get that information by joining the two tables.